How can I replace a two-way switch with a three-way switch?
Old 1960s light switch controls ceiling light with just 2 screws, 1 red wire to 1 screw, 2 black wires wrapped around 1 screw. I want to change to new switch that has 3 screws. I tried separating the 2 black wires to their own screw. The ceiling didn't work but the outlets were now controlled by switch.

Why? Those types of switches have different purposes and use cases. What problem are you trying to solve? Your best bet is to use the same type of switch.

Most electric screws are one wire per screw.
Connect the two black wires to a short black wire with a wire nut and connect the short black to the screw.
You seem to have a three way switch.  Three way switches are usually used when you have two switches controlling a light/s, but can be used as a simple one way switch.
Place the two blacks on the dark colour screw as above and the red on one of the light coloured screw, like on the old switch.
The short wire might be 14 or 12 gauge, the gauge should be on the cable.  If unknown or cannot see the size, 12 gauge is a good choice.  14 gauge cannot be on a 20 amp circuit/breaker, but 12 gauge is good for 15 and 20 amp circuits.

The easiest and correct solution is to get a switch with two screws but you'd still have to pigtail the two black wires together because your not suposed to put two wires under one screw.
You apparently have a three-way switch. After pigtailing the black wires together, attach them to one of the brass screws. Attach the red wire to the dark/black screw. You might have to rotate the switch to get the paddle/toggle in the right position, up on, down off.

Thanks, how do I know the correct type of wire to obtain to pigtail?

Thank you. How do I determine the correct wire to obtain to pigtail the 2 black wires?

@Kandie  Just to play it safe, use #12 if on a 15 or 20 amp breaker.  The lengths of wire coming out of the box are small so there's a good chance the actual wire size won't be shown or won't be legible
